# Cannot update JLabel background in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have a label, `redLabel`, that I will need to change the background of multiple times. I have used NetBeans built-in GUI generator to make the GUI and the generation code is:

```
redLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
redLabel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(110, 110, 110));
redLabel.setOpaque(true);
```

To change the colour, I have tried `redLabel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255,0,0))`, but this does nothing. I even tried adding `redLabel.repaint()` after the code.

The code does not thrown an error when I try to update the code, but it does not change the colour.

So my question is, how do I change the background colour, as the other methods on this site haven't worked.

EDIT: The structure of the code:

```
imports

class noiseBarUi

    public noiseBarUI()
        initComponents()     //auto-generated

    private void initComponents()
        label creation
        set gui
        label property assignment

    public static void main(String args[])
        some code to do with audio sampling
        instantiate class
        try to modify labels    //this doesn't work

    label declarations    //autogenerated

    some method I created
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: The code snippet in this question was edited to be shorter, but the OP still has not posted an MCVE / SSCCE, so voting to close.

Comment: The code is correct. It constructs a `JLabel` with dark grey background.

Comment: @c0der The label is correctly created the first time, however, I cannot change the colour, see "To change the colour..."

Comment: Have you checked if you are not creating another JLabel object by mistake? I.e the one that is being displayed is different object and the one you are setting background to is another object?

Comment: It is important to know how and where you are calling the `setBackground` from.

Comment: @matt The `setBackground` is being called in `main()`. Later it will go in an if statement, but I can't get it to work in the first place.

Comment: Did you call it before or after you created the label and displayed the gui? Did you call it on the EDT?

Comment: I called it after the GUI and label was created. I don't know if I called it on the EDT. I will edit the post to show the structure of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo that changes label color (also demonstrates what [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should look like):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

    private static final int WIDTH = 250, HEIGHT = 200;
    private Color[] colors;
    private int colorIndex = 0;
    private JLabel redLabel;

    public MainWindow() {

        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setColors();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        add(mainPanel);

        redLabel = new JLabel("A Test Label");
        redLabel.setBackground(colors[colorIndex]);
        redLabel.setOpaque(true);
        redLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        mainPanel.add(redLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JButton button = new JButton("Manual Color Change");
        button.addActionListener( e-> changeColor() );
        mainPanel.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setColors() {

        colors = new Color[] {
                new Color(110, 110, 110),
                Color.CYAN,
                Color.RED,
                Color.YELLOW
                };
    }

    private void changeColor() {

        colorIndex = ((colorIndex+1) >= colors.length) ? 0 : colorIndex+1;
        redLabel.setBackground(colors[colorIndex]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        MainWindow win = new MainWindow();
        //auto change color every 2 sec
        new Timer(2000, e-> win.changeColor()).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround your JLabel with a JPanel, and change JPanel border color or background wherever you want.

Some code

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
pane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red))
pane.setBackground(new Color(*RGB*));
```